# Fiber Product with Inclusion Map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Then for open $U \subseteq Y$, I believe it is true that $X \times_Y U = f^{-1}(U)$, but I am not sure how to make rigorous the following proof sketch:

Just as in the construction of the fiber product, cover $Y = \cup \mathrm{Spec} ~B$, and for each $B$, cover $\pi^{-1}(\mathrm{Spec} ~B) = \cup \mathrm{Spec} ~A^B_{\alpha}$. 
Finally, take a basic open cover (since $\mathrm{Spec} ~B \cap U$ is open) $\mathrm{Spec} ~B  \cap U = \cup D(g)$.
Then we have the following commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}$

$
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Spec}(A_{\alpha}^B \otimes_B B_g) = D(f^{\#}(g)) @>i>> \mathrm{Spec}(A_{\alpha}^B)\\@VV V @VV f V\\ D(f) = \mathrm{Spec}~B_f @>i>> \mathrm{Spec} ~B
\end{CD}
$

Thus, we have $\mathrm{Spec} ~(A_{\alpha}^B \otimes B_f) = \pi^{-1}(\mathrm{Spec} ~B \cap U)$. Is it then true that "glueing" will give us $U \times_Y X = f^{-1}(U)$? I have learned about fiber products very recently, so it is still difficult for me to fill in details.

Comment: Do you have any conditions on $U$? Your parenthetical "since $\operatorname{Spec} B\cap U$ is open" suggests that $U$ is open, but you do not mention this elsewhere.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, $U$ is open. I'll change that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the fiber product in the category of sets, the equality is clear.